# Spring-data when update Object cascaded relationship duplicate childs

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm creating an application using Spring-Data with jpa annotations.

I have a many to many relationship defined between Question and Choice, so I have a QuestionChoice object to break the many to many relationship in two.

What I'm trying to accomplish is that when a Question is saved, all the related choices are saved/updated along with the Question.

This is my code so far:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "question",
         cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<QuestionChoice> questionChoices;
…
}

@Entity
@Table(name="question_choice")
public class QuestionChoice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="questionId", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Question question;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="choiceId", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Choice choice;

     …
 }

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHOICE")
public class Choice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "choice")
    private List<QuestionChoice> questions;
 …

}

@Repository
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question,Long> {

}
```

The code is working almost fine. When I create a new object, the Question, Question_Choice and Choice table records are correctly created.

The problem is when I try to add a new Chocie after the Question object was saved... the repository insert all the choices again, instead of insert only the newly added choice...

In the following JUnit example, the last assertEquals tells me there 3 childs instead of 2:

```
@Test 
public void TestSaveQuestionAndAddChoices(){
    Question testQuestion = new Question();
    testQuestion.setDescription("Test");
    testQuestion.setClarification("Test Clarification");
    testQuestion.setAnswerExplanation("Test Answer");
    testQuestion.setLinkForAdditionalInformation("https://link5.com");
    testQuestion.setPoints(7);
    testQuestion.setTimeToAnswer(100);

    /** Check if the Question Id is correct Changed by the Save Method */
    Assert.assertEquals(0, testQuestion.getId());
    dao.getQuestionRepo().save(testQuestion);
    Assert.assertNotEquals(0, testQuestion.getId());

    /** Check Adding a Choice after the Question was saved & save*/
    Choice choice1 = new Choice("Test - Choice 1");
    testQuestion.addChoice(choice1, false);

    dao.getQuestionRepo().save(testQuestion);

    /* Retrieve the Question and verify the Size of the Array */
    Question retrievedQuestion =         dao.getQuestionRepo().findOne(testQuestion.getId());
    Assert.assertEquals(1, retrievedQuestion.getQuestionChoices().size());

    /** Check Adding a Second Choice and save  */       
    testQuestion.addChoice(new Choice("Test - Choice 2"), false);

    dao.getQuestionRepo().save(testQuestion);

    Question retrievedQuestion2 = dao.getQuestionRepo().findOne(testQuestion.getId());

    Assert.assertEquals(2, retrievedQuestion2.getQuestionChoices().size());

}
```

Any explanation will be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: try - testQuestion = dao.getQuestionRepo().save(testQuestion); - the reference is probably not being updated